# Using NLTK to perform document classification on website content issues with BeautifulSoup and NaiveBayes

Tags: python, nlp, classification, nltk, document-classification

I have a Python 2.7 project where I want to classify websites based on their content. I have a database in which I numerous website URLs and their associated category. There are many categories (= labels), and I wish to classify new sites into the corresponding category based on their content. I've been following the NLTK classification tutorial/example listed [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html), but have run into some problems I cannot explain.

Here is an outline of the process that I use:

1. Use MySQLdb to retrieve the category associated with a given website URL. 
      This will be used when extracting data (content) from the URL to pair it with the
      category (= label) of the site.
2. Use a getSiteContent(site) function to extract the content from a website

The above function looks like this:

```
def getSiteContent(site):
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(site, timeout = 1)
        htmlSource = response.read()
    except Exception as e: # <=== some websites may be inaccessible as list isn't up-to-date
        global errors
        errors += 1
        return ''

    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)
    for script in soup.find_all('script'):
        script.extract()

    commonWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    commonWords.update(['function', 'document', 'window', 'functions',     'getElementsByTagName', 'parentNode', 'getDocumentById', 'javascript', 'createElement',     'Copyright', 'Copyrights', 'respective', 'owners', 'Contact Us', 'Mobile Version', 'FAQ',     'Privacy Policy', 'Terms of Service', 'Legal Disclaimer' ])

    text = soup.get_text()

    # Remove ',', '/', '%', ':'
    re.sub(r'(\\d+[,/%:]?\\d*)', '', text)
    # Remove digits
    re.sub(r'\d+', '', text)
    # Remove non-ASCII
    re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]',' ', text)
    # Remove stopwords
    for word in commonWords :
        text = text.replace(' '+word+' ', ' ')

    # Tokenize the site content using NLTK
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)

    # We collect some word statistics, i.e. how many times a given word appears in the     text
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for token in tokens:
        counts[token] += 1

    features = {}
    # Get rid of words that appear less than 3 times
    for word in tokens:
        if counts[word] >= 3 :
            features['count(%s)' % word] = counts[word]

    return features
```

When all the above is done, I do the following:

```
train = getTrainingSet(n)
random.shuffle(train)
```

Where n is the number of sites I wish to train my model against.

Afterwards, I do:

```
feature_set = []
count = 0
for (site, category) in train:
    result = getSiteContent(site)
    count += 1
    if result != '':
        print "%d. Got content for %s" % (count, site)
        feature_set.append((result, category))
    else  :
        print "%d. Failed to get content for %s" % (count, site)
```

The print statements are mainly for debugging purposes at this time. After I do the above, `feature_set` contains something similar to the following:

```
print feature_set
[({u'count(import)': 22, u'count(maxim)': 22, u'count(Maxim)': 5, u'count(css)': 22, u'count(//www)': 22, u'count(;)': 22, u'count(url)': 22, u'count(Gift)': 3, u"count('')": 44, u'count(http)': 22, u'count(&)': 3, u'count(ng16ub)': 22, u'count(STYLEThe)': 3, u'count(com/modules/system/system)': 4, u'count(@)': 22, u'count(?)': 22}, 'Arts & Entertainment'), ({u'count(import)': 3, u'count(css)': 3, u'count(\u05d4\u05d9\u05d5\u05dd)': 4, u'count(\u05de\u05d9\u05dc\u05d5\u05df)': 6, u'count(;)': 3, u'count(\u05e2\u05d1\u05e8\u05d9)': 4, u'count(\u05d0\u05ea)': 3, u'count(\u05de\u05d5\u05e8\u05e4\u05d9\u05e7\u05e1)': 6, u"count('')": 6, u'count(\u05d4\u05d5\u05d0)': 3, u'count(\u05e8\u05d1\u05de\u05d9\u05dc\u05d9\u05dd)': 3, u'count(ver=01122014_4)': 3, u'count(|)': 4, u'count(``)': 4, u'count(@)': 3, u'count(?)': 7}, 'Miscellaneous')]
```

Afterwards, I try to train my classifier and then run it against the test data that I extract from `feature_set`

```
train_set, test_set = feature_set[len(train)/2:], feature_set[:len(train)/2]
print "Num in train_set: %d" % len(train_set)
print "Num in test_set: %d" % len(test_set)
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set) # <=== classified declared on train_set
print classifier.show_most_informative_features(5)
print "=== Classifying a site ==="
print classifier.classify(getSiteContent("http://www.mangaspoiler.com"))
print "Non-working sites: %d" % errors
print "Classifier accuracy: %d" % nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
```

This is pretty much exactly how the tutorial on the NLTK documentation website does it. However, the results are the following (given a set of 100 websites):

```
$ python classify.py
Num in train_set: 23
Num in test_set: 50
Most Informative Features
            count(Pizza) = None           Arts & : Techno =      1.0 : 1.0
None
=== Classifying a site ===
Technology & Computing
Non-working sites: 27
Classifier accuracy: 0
```

---

Now, there are obviously a few problems with this:

1. The word tokens contain unicode characters such as `\u05e2\u05d1\u05e8\u05d9`, as it seems that the regex for removing them only works if they are standalone. This is a minor problem.
2. A bigger problem is that even when I `print` the `feature_set`, the word tokens are displayed as `u'count(...)' = #` as opposed to `'count(...)' = #`. I think this may be a bigger issue and part of why my classifier is failing.
3. The classifier is, obviously, failing catastrophically as some point. The accuracy is listed as `0` even if I feed my entire dataset into the classifier, which seems extremely unlikely.
4. The `Most Informative Features` function says that `count(Pizza) = None`. The code where I declare `defaultdict(int)`, however, requires that every entry be associated with the number of appearances in the text.

---

I am at quite a loss as to why this happens. As far as I can tell, my data is structured identically to the data that the NLTK documentation uses in its tutorial on the website I linked at the top of this question. If anyone who has worked with NLTK has seen this behaviour before, I would greatly appreciate any tips as to what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: FYI, I removed the comment regarding the close vote from the question because the [Close Votes review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6399136) ended with a unanimous vote to leave open.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably many errors here, but the first and most obvious one stands out here:

> The accuracy is listed as `0` even if I feed my entire dataset into the classifier

It's not listed as `0.0`? It sounds like something in there that ought to be a `float` is an `int`. I suspect you're doing division at some point for a normalization, and the `int/int` isn't getting converted into `float`.

While building your count table, add `1.0` for each count, not `1`. That will fix the source of the problem, and the corrections will trickle-down.

If it seems strange to count documents with floats, think of each count as a *measurement* in the scientific sense of the word rather than a representation of a discrete document.